# Why are negative temperature coefficient thermistors accurate for measurements of low temperatures?

Tags: electricity, temperature, electrical-resistance

Why are [negative temperature coefficient thermistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor#NTC) accurate for measurements of low temperatures? How does higher resistance at low temperature accurately measure the temperature?

Comment: Consider the impact of noise on measurements of low resistances. Now consider the joy of an increasing resistance with decreasing temperature. Also consider, for a fixed voltage to sense the thermistor resistance, the power dissipated by the thermistor in a low temperature experiment.

Comment: I didn't get it. Plz explain. My level of understanding is not that high.

Comment: (1) Noise is a factor in all accurate measurements. Accurately measuring small resistances will be plagued with noise. (2) Power dissipation goes as V$^{2}$/R for fixed voltage - you don't want to be dumping power into the experiment you want to get really cold.

Answer (score 2):

[Ruthenium oxide NTC thermistors](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruthenium+oxide+thermometer) are commonly used in very low temperature cryogenics (down to ~0.01 kelvin). At a guess, the main concerns engineers faced in making this choice is 1) stability of resistance over many cooldown cycles, 2) low magnetoresistance effects, 3) a decent relative temperature coefficient at the low temperatures, and 4) easy, low noise measurement without heating effects.

The last two criteria are key for low temperatures. Positive coefficient thermistors tend to saturate below the few-kelvin level, or their resistance falls to an extremely low value. To measure low resistance values with accuracy, you need high currents, which means either thick, conductive cables going down to the thermometer, or running the risk of dumping too much Joule heat into the system. Unfortunately, conductive cables themselves bring in a lot of heat as they have high thermal conductance as well!

So the best way to go is a high resistance thermometer with very thin wires.